# Delete data without collision? (JMeter)

Tags: jmeter

I have 3 thread groups: POST, GET and DELETE. They are consuming from database. The POST and GET request purpose is clear - adding and getting data to/from DB. DELETE is deleting, but at some point, because all the threads are running in parallel (consecutively is unchecked) it happen that it is trying to get records that were just deleted and that lead to not successful response. I'm trying to get the best throughput from all 3 endpoints, so I think Synchronization timer won't be a solution, so I'm wondering what else can be tried in order to fix this and avoid that problem.

What I tried so far - tried to set the GET to take records from last added records into the table, since DELETE is taking from the first added, but at some point it keep throwing conflict errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing the [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) problems while doing your load testing the real users (or upstream systems) of your application will face the same problems in production.

It might be the case you're passing data between thread groups is wrong and you're trying to delete the data which hasn't been generated yet or something like this. Try using i.e. [Inter Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin or write the generated IDs or something into a CSV file and read them in "get" and "delete" thread groups using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

So I fail to see what you're trying to achieve from JMeter side. If you want to just measure the endpoint throughput - run 3 separate tests or pre-generate entities for getting and deletion somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)

Comment: No, I'm not passing data between the threads. The first step of each thread is to make a DB request and scrape 100 records. Then 1 by 1 those records are passed in foreach controller, where for GET I execute a get request against all those scraped records, and for DELETE I'm just deleting them. The problem is that due to the high load, there's a moment when those records are deleted, but they are already scraped from the GET SQL query thread, which is a problem, because they doesn't exist.

Comment: Let me give an example:
We have 10 users: User1, User2, User3, User4, User5, User6, User7, User8, User9, User10

1. DELETE Users SQL query takes first 3 users
2. GET Users SQL query takes first 3 users
3. First 3 users are deleted by the DELETE query, 1 by 1 in the foreach loop
4. First 3 users are tried to be listed by the GET, but they already doesn't exist, because they were deleted by the DELETE call

Comment: It is not "due to high load", if each thread fetches 100 records (the same dataset) and then either GETs or DELETEs them you may run into a situation when the record has been deleted already and GET request hasn't been executed yet. You need to redesign your test, i.e. use [OFFSET and LIMIT](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-limit/) clauses so each thread would have its own data. Double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) combination and you will see